# wp_list_category only showing to logged in uers

Tags: categories

I am trying to print categories at front end using

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'style'              => 'list',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 0,
'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'feed'               => '',
'feed_type'          => '',
'feed_image'         => '',
'exclude'            => '',
'exclude_tree'       => '',
'include'            => '',
'hierarchical'       => 1,
'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
'show_option_none'   => __( 'No categories' ),
'number'             => null,
'echo'               => 1,
'depth'              => 0,
'current_category'   => 0,
'pad_counts'         => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'walker'             => null
);
wp_list_categories( $args ); 
?>
```

The above code only shows up to logged in user.
They wouldn't show up for non-logged in users

Any suggestions.?

Comment: You are being contradictory when say "The above code only shows up to logged in user. They wouldn't show up for non-logged in users". Can you explain better what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is not with wp_list_categories, it has no options for hiding output based on role.

Comment: @cybmeta The problem is that it would fetch and print the categories if the user is logged in. If user isnt logged in ,it returns null
MikeGWP yeah even thats makin me confused.
Can it be a Host Issue